# Malloc array of struct in C

Tags: c

Here is what I do:
I count the number of file inside a folder, get data from this file inside a array of struct.
I want to malloc this array of struct, since I do not know the exact number of file before strating the program.

Here is my code:

```
struct get_data{
int sequence;
int mask_ID;
char *name;
float intensity;
float angle_correction;
double points[10000];
float X_interval;
};

struct get_data all_data[number_of_file];
```

Consider I get number_of_file before somewhere in the program.
I want to know how to malloc the struct all_data. I search but got lost at some point. Any help would be welcomed. Thank you.

Mel.

Comment: You almost get there, do search with `malloc`

Comment: Nominally, you'd write `struct get_data *all_data = malloc(sizeof(*all_data) * number_of_file);` and check that the allocation worked before using `all_data` (the pointer) in array expressions as before. That's a very basic use of `malloc()`.  If the array is a file scope variable, then you define the pointer at file scope, but allocate the space for it to point to inside a function.  Check that the variable is not null before using it as an array (for example, `assert(all_data != 0);` at judicious points in the code).

Comment: There is no code. Only some declarations. We are not a coding service.

Comment: Thank you, it was what I was looking for. However, why do you need to use a pointer to all_data, and not just      struct get_data all_data = malloc(sizeof(all_data) * number_of_file);

Comment: `malloc` return a pointer (an address) to the memory that was allocated. So, that is why you need to use a pointer.

Comment: Thank you. A lot :)

Comment: @Melponeme  `object_pointer = malloc(sizeof *object_pointer * number_of_element);` is always right.  `object_pointer = malloc(sizeof (object_pointer_ref_type) * number_of_element);` is 1) more prone to be mis-coded (whas the rigth type used?) , 2) harder to review (need to find the type)  3) harder to maintain. (more changes should pointer type change).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give a fixed length to the name variable inside the structure or else you would have to `malloc` that for each structure. The declaration could look like this:

```
struct get_data
{
    int sequence;
    int mask_ID;
    char name[256];
    float intensity;
    float angle_correction;
    double points[10000];
    float X_interval;
};
```

Then, you may `malloc` an array of structures using the following code:

```
struct get_data *all_data;

all_data = malloc(number_of_files * sizeof(struct get_data));
if (all_data == NULL)
{
    printf("Malloc failed!\n);
    return -1;
}

/* now you can access each file structure using a for instruction */
int i;
for (i = 0; i < number_of_files; i++)
{
    all_data[i].sequence = ...;
    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: One could also use [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) to allocate a variable-length `struct` in a single call to `malloc`  so the first paragraph is not exactly right.

Comment: True, but what if he had more than one flexible array members? It was just a suggestion to simplify the declaration as OP seems to be still learning basic memory management concepts in C.

Comment: if number_of_files is signed , using calloc would avoid  signed overflow. Any drawbacks ?